# Developer Story font colour

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, developer-story, safari

In the developer story editing page, when you hover over the % circle for tags it looks like the following:

[image: Hover 1]

Whereas in the public story (https://stackoverflow.com/story/xxxx) it looks like the following:

[image: Hover 2]

Edit:

Also seems to be happening on the Safari mobile site, IOS 10:

[image: IOS]

Black on dark grey = very hard to read

Comment: Looks normal to me (Chrome 53 and Firefox 49, Windows 10). Added a Safari tag.

Comment: No repro Safari 10.0

Comment: I'm also using 10.0 but still seeing the dark text.. strange

Comment: I can't repro this too, which browser/os are you using?

Comment: Safari 10.0 with OSX Sierra. Must just be an issue on my end, although I've got no idea what would be causing it

Comment: @Stéphane, seems to be also happening on the mobile version of Safari, edited question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to fix this bug, it'll be live after one of our next production builds.